# Simple JSP page is not working

Tags: java, jsp

May be i am doing a blunder simplest mistake , and i know this platform is not suitable for asking this one simplest question. 
But i am learning java technology by self , and i am trying to run simple JSP.

I made a JSP page in WebContent , added required jar

But when i try to run this jSP the output is same what i have wrote in JSP page..

output in browser is

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>First JSP Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<% out.print("Hi JSP"); %>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using Eclipse Kepler with JDK 1.7 and Apache 7

**Not sure where i have done mistake , Kindly help me . Apologies for asking the simplest one**

Comment: *the output is same what i have wrote in JSP page* what you actually want your question is not very clear

Comment: Do you have apache http server or apache TomCat???

Comment: Is the extension of the file .JSP? if not change it to JSP. How do you open this JSP file? You should do it through `http://localhost...`, not directly from the file system (`file:///...` in the address bar would be wrong).

Comment: Your JSP is not being executed by your server - it is being served as a text file - check your webapp / application server configs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all Configure the Tomcat in eclipse [refer this for configuring tomcat](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jst/components/ws/M4/tutorials/InstallTomcat.html)
Once tomcat is configured right-click on the project and run it on server. Once the server is started it will automatically redirect you to some page configured in web.xml under `<welcome-file>` tag so to check your jsp is working or not just type the url

```
http://localhost:8080/yourProjectName/yourJspPageName.jsp
```

Comment: I did the same , as above mentioned .. But not sure every time it is showing same result.. I correctly configured the tomCat

Comment: Hi ur jsp page is working I tried in my local check whether this posted code is same  to ur working code sometimes a small tag mistake corrupts everything

Answer (score 1):

Your jsp page is absolutely fine.May be ur configuration are wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested and there are no error in your file. Try `http://localhost:8080/example.jsp` or use this source code:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>First JSP Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
    out.print("Hi JSP");
%>
</body>
</html>
```